# i18next: How to avoid TS6133-error 'foo' is declared but its value is never read?

Tags: javascript, i18next, react-i18next

**[Solved]** I was wondering how I can avoid the `TS6133-error: 'var' is declared but its value is never read` in connection with i18next? Basically I have a function `labelForTeaserStyle(style: TeaserStyle)` that is read in this line of code:

```
<Typography variant="subtitle1" color="gray">
    Style: {labelForTeaserStyle(style)}
</Typography>

function labelForTeaserStyle(style: TeaserStyle) {
  switch (style) {
    case TeaserStyle.Default:
      return 'Default'

    case TeaserStyle.Light:
      return 'Light'

    case TeaserStyle.Text:
      return 'Text'
  }
```

However, when applying i18next to this line of code it would throw me the TS6133-error `'labelForTeaserStyle' is declared but its value is never read`.

I have read about using `/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */` just before the line which causes the error but that doesn't help. Another suggestion that I've read is to deactivate `noUnusedLocals` in tsconfig.json, however this is not an option for me since I want to keep this option activated.

The question for me is now whether I somehow can embed i18next-code so that the compiler still recognises `labelForTeaserStyle()` as being used/read?

**Code with i18next**:

```
<Typography variant="subtitle1" color="gray">
    {t('styleInterpolated', {labelForTeaserStyle(style)})}
</Typography>
```

**Keys**:

```
"styleInterpolated": "Style: {{function}}"
```

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer so that others with the same problem can find it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm rather new here. Will post it as an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

I found the answer to my question. The thing is I'm having ESLint and TSLint at the same time implemented and therefore using `// @ts-ignore` alone wouldn't solve the problem. The solution was to also add `/* eslint-disable */`. Here's the working code:

```
/* eslint-disable */
// @ts-ignore
function labelForTeaserStyle(style: TeaserStyle) {
  (...)
}
```